# No response for success call after form submiting

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making simple contact form which now send successfully each message but I don't see response after function success i.e. message that the mail is sent.. errors.. etc.
This is my js

```
    var submitContact = $('#submit'),
    message = $('#msg');

submitContact.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'contact.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {

            if(data.info !== 'error'){
                $this.parents('form').find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible').val('');
                message.hide().removeClass('success').removeClass('error').addClass('success').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');

            } else {
        message("Thank you!");
                message.hide().removeClass('success').removeClass('error').addClass('error').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my form

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
               <input class="form-field" name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
               <input class="form-field" name="mail" id="mail" type="text" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="form-field" name="subjectForm" id="subjectForm" type="text" placeholder="Subject">
           </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
                <textarea class="form-field" name="messageForm" id="messageForm" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div class="submit-area">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="button button3">Send</button>
                <div id="msg" class="message"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Why `<div id="msg" class="message"></div>` doesn't display anything? I've received emails in my inbox from the form so it is working..?

```
General
Request URL:http://example.com/contact.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address: IP
Response Headers

Response Headers   view source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 28 Jun 2016 09:40:19 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=5
Server:Apache

Request Headers view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, lzma
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:220
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Host:example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/contact.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36 OPR/38.0.2220.31
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data  view source  view URL encoded
name:fsdfsdfdsfsd
mail:my@email.com
subjectForm:fsfsdfsf
messageForm:fsdfdsfds
```

Comment: Have you checked that the response of the request is `200 OK`?

Comment: Yes, on the console of the browser i see Response is 200 ok

Comment: `Request Method:POST Status Code:200 OK`

Comment: But this is under `headers` tab. On `Response` tab there is nothing

Comment: Are you sure there's no `ReferenceError` like "`data` is not defined" or "can not get property `info` of `undefined`"?

Comment: Yes, hundred percents

Comment: I have updated my question with that I see in console